# Are these topologies in $\mathbb R$ am I on the right track?

Tags: general-topology

I have just been introduced to what a topology is.  I understand that there are 3 requirements that must be met. My definition is

1. $\mathbb R \in \mathfrak T$ and $ \emptyset \in \mathfrak T$
2. If $ V_\alpha \in \mathfrak T $ for each $\alpha \in \lambda $ then $\bigcup \{ V_\alpha : \alpha \in \lambda \} \in \mathfrak T$.
3. If $V_i \in \mathfrak T$ for $ i = 1, 2, ...n$ then $ \bigcap \{ V_i : i = 1, 2,.... n \} \in \mathfrak T$

So my general understanding of parts 2 and 3 is what I am considered about. 2 states that arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathfrak T$ are $\in \mathfrak T$ and 3 states finite intersections of elements of $\mathfrak T$ are in $\mathfrak T$.

I can deal with all that... now I have to determine whether or not the following are topologies for $\mathbb R$

a. $ \{\mathbb R$,$\emptyset$, $(-\infty, 0] $, $ (0, \infty)$$\}$

b. $ \{\mathbb R$,$\emptyset$, $(-\infty, 1) $, $ (0, \infty)$$\}$

c. $ \{\mathbb R$,$\emptyset$, $\{1 \}$$\}$

d.  $\{ U : U$ = $\mathbb R$ or $ U = \emptyset$ or $ U =$  $[a, +\infty)$ for some a $\in \mathbb R \}$

e.  $ \{\mathbb R$,$\emptyset$, $(1, 3) $, $ (2,4)$$\}$

I have a couple more examples but I would like to start with these.

I think a and d are the only ones that are topologies but I am not even sure if I am on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that (a) is a topology on $\Bbb R$. However, the only other topology in the list is (c), not (d).

- (b) is not closed under taking finite intersections: $(-\infty,1)\cap(0,\infty)=(0,1)$ is not in the supposed topology.
- (d) is not closed under taking unions: $\bigcup_{a>0}[a,\infty)=(0,\infty)$, which is not in the supposed topology.
- (e) is not closed under taking unions *or* finite intersections: $(1,3)\cup(2,4)=(1,4)$ and $(1,3)\cap(2,4)=(2,3)$ are not in the supposed topology.

Comment: Thank you I think I am starting to wrap my brain around this! So would $ \{\mathbb R$,$\emptyset$, $[-\infty, 0] $, $ [0, \infty]$$\}$ be a topology ? I think yes?

Comment: @Alyssa: Not quite. First, you mean $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, since $-\infty$ and $\infty$ aren’t in $\Bbb R$. But even with that change it isn’t quite a topology, because $(-\infty,0]\cap[0,\infty)=\{0\}$, which isn’t in your list of sets. If you make it $\{\Bbb R,\varnothing,(-\infty,0],[0,\infty),\{0\}\}$, you have a topology on $\Bbb R$.